# call zeroEx.exchange.fillOrderAsync throw Error: Contract call failed (returned null)

Tags: 0x

I have created order ,but when I call fillOrderAsync encounter a error.
Contract call failed (returned null),Help me please!

fillOrder.callAsync { from: '0xe9c6f611639f1cb7b23af24a3519385f6b8d4c91',
  gas: undefined,
  gasPrice: undefined } 0xb4be83d50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016345785d8a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a00000000000000000000000004ea6d528600c7467257065dd3c32a758b61fa9de00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004ea6d528600c7467257065dd3c32a758b61fa9de0000000000000000000000004ea6d528600c7467257065dd3c32a758b61fa9de00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c68af0bb1400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000429d069189e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000773594000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000077359400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001656b164a6d9218ae5f4c25d91b3b1da24ab06b1b0be0502cd6267f845024ede7c34dfdcc82000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024f47261b0000000000000000000000000d0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024f47261b0000000000000000000000000d0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000421ca94325aeecb3f1c4e8d1bb2a218a268575e4b04276da8b6cd726bf7760b03db7474531b766724bc242af3ef39924f9078fcbb496f89a501e1e63ab09342a438f03000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { gasPrice: BigNumber { s: 1, e: 3, c: [ 1000 ] } }

```
const FillOrder = async (signedOrder) => {

    /*
    try {
    const isOrderValid = await zeroEx.exchange.validateOrderFillableOrThrowAsync(signedOrder);
    console.log('isOrderValid', isOrderValid);
    } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    }
    */

    //const shouldThrowOnInsufficientBalanceOrAllowance = true;

    const fillTakerTokenAmount = ZeroEx.toBaseUnitAmount(new BigNumber(0.1), DECIMALS);
    const txHash = await zeroEx.exchange.fillOrderAsync(
    signedOrder,
    fillTakerTokenAmount,
        takerAddress.toLowerCase()
    );
    console.log('txHash', txHash);
    const txReceipt = await zeroEx.awaitTransactionMinedAsync(txHash);
    console.log('FillOrder transaction receipt: ', txReceipt);

}


var web3Wrapper = new Web3Wrapper(engine);

const configs = {networkId: NETWORK_ID, gasPrice:1000,
    gasPrice:new BigNumber(1000),
    exchangeContractAddress:'0x90fe2af704b34e0224bf2299c838e04d4dcf1364',
    tokenRegistryContractAddress:'0xf18e504561f4347bea557f3d4558f559dddbae7f',
    zrxContractAddress:'0x6ff6c0ff1d68b964901f986d4c9fa3ac68346570',
    };

const zeroEx = new ZeroEx(engine, configs);

const WETH_ADDRESS = '0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c';//zeroEx.etherToken.getContractAddressIfExists();
const ZRX_ADDRESS = zeroEx.exchange.getZRXTokenAddress().toLowerCase();
const EXCHANGE_ADDRESS = zeroEx.exchange.getContractAddress().toLowerCase();

console.log('WETH_ADDRESS', WETH_ADDRESS);
console.log('ZRX_ADDRESS', ZRX_ADDRESS);
console.log('EXCHANGE_ADDRESS', EXCHANGE_ADDRESS);


zeroEx.getAvailableAddressesAsync()
.then((addresses)=>{
    console.log('zeroEx Addresses',addresses);
    if(addresses.length>0)
    {
        takerAddress = addresses[0];
        web3Wrapper.getBalanceInWeiAsync(takerAddress).then((balance)=>
        {
            console.log('getBalanceInWeiAsync',balance.toString());

            fs.readFile('signedOrder.txt', function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.error(err);
                }
                FillOrder(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
            });
        }
        );
    }
});
```

(node:749148) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Contract call failed (returned null)
    at Web3Wrapper. (C:\Projects\BlockChain\0xproject-demo\1.0.1\node_modules\0x.js\node_modules\@0xproject\web3-wrapper\lib\src\web3_wrapper.js:728:35)